# how to handle an exception thrown from within outer catch block in bpel1.1, Oracle SOA 11g

Tags: soa, bpel, fault, catch-block

how to handle an exception thrown from within outer catch block in bpel1.1.
I tried to publish a queue 'Q1' from bpel but i got an exception while accessing it.
Exception got handled in fault policy from where it was re thrown and got handled in a catch block. For some reason we are publishing the same queue 'Q1' again. and again we got the exception. So how can i handle that exception. Please throw some light.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to handle error exception in bpel.

Oracle has provided AIA framwork for BPEL message flow and error handling.

if you are using it then it has predefined templates and you have to just migrate in your code.

also for your specific scenario all catch block will help.